# Determining the properties of the Bisection method.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, bisection

If we use bisection to determine the roots of a function, can we say that the closer the function values of the two starting points are to zero, the faster the process converges? Also what happens if we have more than $2$ roots in the start interval? Will bisection then not converge?

Comment: The rate of convergence won't change if the starting interval is shorter (convergence is linear), but the number of steps to reach a given precision will be reduced. But pay attention to Yves Daoust's answer as your condition does not necessarily mean the starting interval is shorter.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: if the numbers are represented by floating-point, a shorter interval does not necessarily means faster convergence. The number of significant bits can be the same.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I meant *absolute* precision. Of course you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, not necessarily. For instance the endpoints of the interval might be close to nearby roots, outside.

2) If the function is continuous and you have a change of sign, you will converge to one of the roots (unpredictably which one).

---

It is not a simple matter to check convergence based on the function values, because a test to zero is not meaningful as long as you don't have a reference order of magnitude. To illustrate, notice that $f(x)$ and $10000 f(x)$ have precisely the same roots, but the function values differ by a factor $10000$.

In the case of bissection, you know exactly where you are going on the $x$'s, because every iteration brings one more exact bit. Note that when you are getting real close to a root, chances are high that the evaluations of $f$ become very inaccurate and even wrong in sign. It is useless to continue the iterations past that point.